# Reference in a record of a type which is defined afterwards

Tags: delphi, record, pascal

I'm pretty new to Pascal and tried to make a reference to a type which is defined afterwards, but in this way it does not work. 
Is this even possible in Pascal?

```
type
  Node = record
    Name: string;
    Id: integer;
    Routes: array of Route;
  end;

  Route = record
    Distance: integer;
    NodeA, NodeB: Node;
  end;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is simply not possible. You will have to use pointers to either a Route or a Node instead. These can be defined forward.

Comment: There was a question about it here (not the one I marked as duplicate few minutes ago). But I cannot find it (no extra time, sorry).

Comment: Why are you making copies of nodes rather than references? And same question for routes. Why do you want to copy?